# Searchbox on a static page

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a page which contains FAQ.

The idea is to implement a search box which has the look & feel of the one shown on [Font awesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

With a bit of online help I've been able to produce the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
</script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Testing a search bar</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e34d8d1dc9.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/Searchbar.js"></script>
  <link href="/CSS/woff2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/CSS/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" data-view="search">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">
        <section id="search">
          <label for="searchinput"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Search FAQ</span></label>
          <input id="searchinput" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search FAQ" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" tabindex="1">
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="faqs">
      <h3>Question 1</h3>
      <section>
        Answer 1<br> abc
      </section>
      <h3>Question 2</h3>
      <section>
        Answer 2<br>xyz
      </section>
      <h3>Question 3</h3>
      <section>
        Answer 3<br>def
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The code uses 2 css - files:

1. [site.css](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54991757/Webdeveloper.com/Search%20on%20a%20static%20page/site.css)
2. [enter link description here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54991757/Webdeveloper.com/Search%20on%20a%20static%20page/woff2.css)

and 1 [java script file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54991757/Webdeveloper.com/Search%20on%20a%20static%20page/search.js).

Though the page (this is just a test of course) has the look & feel I'm looking for, the search functionality doesn't work yet.

I based it on [on a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Sempervivum/rrkr5sL0/8/)

Can anyone here tell me what I have to do to make it work just like the example?

Comment: add css or more to your tag in the question to attract the right people faster

Comment: Your best bet is to use this, http://listjs.com/, never reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I accidentally posted a link to the wrong js file. It should have been this one: [searchbar.js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54991757/Webdeveloper.com/Search%20on%20a%20static%20page/searchbar.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with a bit of tinkering. :-)

> Testing a search bar
>
> ```
>     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e34d8d1dc9.js"></script> 
>     <script src="/Scripts/FontAwesome.js"></script>
>
>     <%--    <link href="/CSS/woff2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
>             <link href="/CSS/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
>     --%>
>      <link href="/CSS/woff2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
>      <link href="/CSS/searchbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> </head>
> <body>
>     <div class="container" data-view="search">
>         <div class="row">
>             <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">
>                 <section id="search">
>                     <label for="searchinput"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Search
> ```
>
> FAQ
>
> ```
>         <div id="faqs">
>             <h3>Question 1</h3>
>             <section>
>                 Answer 1<br> abc
>             </section>
>             <h3>Question 2</h3>
>             <section>
>                 Answer 2<br>xyz
>             </section>
>             <h3>Question 3</h3>
>             <section>
>                 Answer 3<br>def
>             </section>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>
>     <script src="/Scripts/Searchbar.js"></script>
> </body> </html>
> ```

As you can see I put [searchbar.js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54991757/Webdeveloper.com/Search%20on%20a%20static%20page/searchbar.js) at the lowest level possible, and I replace site.css with [searchbar.css](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54991757/Webdeveloper.com/Search%20on%20a%20static%20page/searchbar.css)

Answer (score 0):

I think an even better solution for this would be to introduce a lightweight MVVM framework like knockout.js. With this you could put all of your FAQ's into a view model and easily add a search functionality that way. This will clean up your HTML significantly, especially if you get more and more FAQ's added to your site.

Comment: And how would I do that? I know what knockout.js is of course, but too me your idea is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting question objects inside an array, then filter them on search:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sjx5uorg/2/

```js
var searchBox = $('#searchinput');
var faqs = [
 {
   question: "This is first question",
    answer: "Answer 1"
  },
 {
   question: "Another question. Second?",
    answer: "Answer 2"
  },
 {
   question: "Question 3",
    answer: "Answer 3"
  },
 {
   question: "Question 4",
    answer: "Answer 4"
  }
]


function updateList(faqArray) {
 var faqList = $('#faq-list');
 faqList.html('');
 $.each(faqArray, function(faq) {
  faq = faqArray[faq];
     faqList.append('<li><h3>'+ faq.question +'</h3><p>'+ faq.answer +'</p></li>');
 });
}

updateList(faqs);

searchBox.keyup(function(event) {
  var searchList = faqs.filter(function(faq){
   var question = faq.question.toLowerCase(); 
    return question.indexOf(searchBox.val().toLowerCase()) >= 0
  });
  updateList(searchList);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<label>
  Search: <input id="searchinput" />
</label>
<ul id="faq-list"></ul>
```

Comment: It was what I originally had in mind, however the FAQ's are being maintained from within a CMS, on a page basis. Basicaly, my client has a team of 3-4 people who pass their time opening every page in the CMS (in each one of the supported language) and editing it directly there. The FAQ's will be offered in one large static page per language, where they can easily add or remove new FAQ's. Though this could be remedied by letting them edit a JSON or even create a small web page which would allow them to do just that they're considered being uncapable of that.